# Error : According to TLD, tag form:input must be empty, but is not

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc form

```
<form:form action="${actionUrl}" method="post" commandName="userAccountVO">
<form:input type="text" path="userName" value="${user.userName}"></input>
//other similar fields
<input type="submit" id="save_changes_button" value="" />
</form:form>
```

In the controller that returns the view I have this code

```
 model.addAttribute(user, userAccountVO);
 model.addAttribute("userAccountVO", new UserAccountVO());
 return "view";
```

But I get the error mentioned above If i put some value in input tag like this

```
 <form:input type="text" path="userName" value="${user.userName}">some text</input>
```

Also, if i try to submit the form all the fields in the model attribute object is null.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/updateuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
GenericResponse updateUserAccount(
        @ModelAttribute("userAccountVO") UserAccountVO userAccountVO,
        BindingResult result) {
 //userAccountVO here is null, i guess it creates a new object
}
```

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/according-to-tld-tag-forminput-must-be-empty-but-is-not/) post says it is because I don't have a form backing object, but I do have.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious advice. Replace

```
<form:input type="text" path="userName" value="${user.userName}"></input>
```

by

```
<form:input path="userName"/>
```

Comment: but I want to preload the text box with a value.

Comment: text field is associated with the object field with the help of Spring forms. so Spring will preload value from passed object automatically

Comment: Well! I never knew this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

**commandName** attribute of form does all the automatic value binding to modal object in spring form, with **path** you will get the value of the corresponding attribute of the modal object.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong, you should change it to:

```
<form:input type="text" path="userName" value="${user.userName}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not give any space, characters or newline in between tags, then it wont give this warning message.